# ImportError: cannot import name tensorboard_server

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, tensorboard

since I pulled the latest updates of the tensorflow repository, I figured out that the tensorboard is no longer functional. I installed from source using bazel-0.1.4. Afterwards, I built the tensorboard as follows:

```
bazel build tensorflow/tensorboard:tensorboard
```

Then, when I'm running it with:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard
```

I'm getting the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/username/tensorflow/bazel-bin/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard.runfiles/tensorflow/tensorboard/backend/tensorboard.py", line 36, in <module>
from tensorflow.tensorboard.backend import tensorboard_server
ImportError: cannot import name tensorboard_server
```

What's wrong? Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [recent commit](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/60765a4b210fc54ec32a7729f8532a60c5217544) added the new module `tensorboard_server` without listing it as a dependency of tensorboard.

I modified tensorflow/tensorboard/BUILD by adding the following section:

```
py_library(
    name = "tensorboard_server",
    srcs = ["backend/tensorboard_server.py"],
    deps = [
        ":float_wrapper",
        "//tensorflow/python:platform",
        "//tensorflow/python:summary",
    ],
    srcs_version = "PY2AND3",
)
```

and added `":tensorboard_server"` to the dependencies of the tensorboard binary.

Following this, I built and ran tensorboard as you specified, and it appears to work:

```
$ bazel build tensorflow/tensorboard:tensorboard
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //tensorflow/tensorboard:tensorboard up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.425s, Critical Path: 0.10s
$ bazel-bin/tensorflow/tensorboard/tensorboard --logdir .
Starting TensorBoard 13 on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://0.0.0.0:6006)
```

Comment: Maybe you should open a [TensorFlow issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).

Comment: Ok thanks! It seems to work in the command line, but when I open it on the browser it's just a blank screen that says _"TensorBoard EVENTS IMAGES GRAPH HISTOGRAMS"_ . Also many error lines on the terminal appear (e.g. `WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.../paper-tabs.html'` ). Did it worked for you in that sense?

Comment: There is/was an issue with _ and - in directory names (they got changed and something broke) - I thought it was fixed in between, my fix at the time was just to copy the directories